# MYSQL: How to select using multiple tags

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables set up like this

**artist**

```
[ artist_id | artist_name | ... ]
```

**genre**

```
[ genre_id | genre_name | ... ]
```

**artist_genre**

```
[ artist_genre_artist_id | artist_genre_genre_id | ... ]
```

An artist (e.g. Queen) has multiple genres like **Rock, glam rock, psychedelic rock, hard rock, progressive rock, punk rock, heavy metal, pop, blues, rock and roll, rhythm 'n blues**.

If I visit a page of other artists like **The Rolling Stone**, I would like to display similar artists like queen based on the current artist's **multiple** genres (tags).

The Rolling Stone does genres like **Rock, blues, rock and roll**.

I want to return results in order of **RELEVANCE** by how many of the current artist's genres appear on the other artists' list.

I don't know if I've made enough sense but I hope you get the point. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try a self join approach with aggregation:

```
SELECT
    a1.artist_name,
    a2.artist_name,
    COUNT(*) AS common_cnt
FROM artist_genre ag1
INNER JOIN artist_genre ag2
    ON ag2.artist_genre_artist_id > ag1.artist_genre_artist_id AND
       ag2.artist_genre_genre_id = ag1.artist_genre_genre_id
INNER JOIN artist a1
    ON a1.artist_id = ag1.artist_genre_artist_id
INNER JOIN artist a2
    ON a2.artist_id = ag2.artist_genre_artist_id
GROUP BY
    a1.artist_name,
    a2.artist_name
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC,
    a1.artist_name,
    a2.artist_name;
```

The strategy here is to bring every artist in comparison to every other artist (without duplication), on the condition that a given junction table record matches genres on both sides of the join.  Then, we aggregate by the pair of artists being compared, and take the number of records, which is the overlap.  Here is a working demo with a small sample data set:

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT artist_genre_genre_id   FROM artist_genre WHERE artist_genre_artist_id  =$login_id;
```

store the above result in array $related_genre

```
SELECT DISTINCT artist.artist_name FROM artist_genre
LEFT JOIN artist
ON artist.artist_id = artist_genre.artist_genre_artist_id
WHERE artist_genre.artist_genre_genre_id   in ($related_genre);
```